# Unable to render static index file from express

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I working on Angular application, where I am trying to server the build files from my Angular application through the dist directory in my express. To do this I copy the files generated by **ng build** and paste them into dist folder of express.

My dist folder looks like below

[image: Dist Folder for Express]

I am using the following code to serve the index.html file

```
this.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'))
```

But seem to be getting "**Cannot GET /**" error

Similarly if I do

```
this.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

it serves the html in the public folder.

As far as my understanding, you can serve static from any folder in express. I am not sure if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make new directory `./dist/www` and move your files except server.js to here.

```
this.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should replace

```
this.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'))
```

with

```
this.app.use(express.static(__dirname))
```

Comment: this did it for me, but i have another issue about not being able to access the bundle files from angular probably create another post about it

Comment: @RRP While this works, it also means your server's code is now publicly available – `GET /server.js`, etc. As botika mentioned, it's recommended to have all static, client-side files in their own directory (e.g. move `dist/index.html` to `dist/public/index.html`) and have `express.static()` serve that directory (`__dirname + '/public'`).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski do you know why this.app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist')) fails, shouldn't it also serve all the static assests under this folder

Comment: @RRP [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) gives you the parent directory of the current script, `server.js`, which is already inside of the `dist` directory. From there, `__dirname + '/dist'` results in `dist/dist/` and that doesn't exist.